# grid images using css flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i would like to build grid image using flex css property like http://www.agefotostock.com/age/en/Search.aspx?perpage=20&query=lion

(use "row view" in display options)

when checking source code, i can see that flex property is dynamic(not the same on each picture).

Apparently the bigest pictures available is equal to 390px width or height (before resizing using flex).

i looking for since 2 weeks through stackoverflow, personal tries and "flex" documentation but without succes.

anyone can give me clues ? how calculate ratio or something else ?

thx in advance, regards !!

Answer (score 3):

After some research ( and lot of cofee ) it seem that i found something interresting

Take a look at code
HTML:

```
<div id="masonry">
  <div><img class="item" data-width="600" data-height="804" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/1.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="600" data-height="791" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/2.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="600" data-height="804" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/1.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="600" data-height="791" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/2.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="1000" data-height="579" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/3.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="1000" data-height="650"src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/4.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="700" data-height="932" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/6.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="1000" data-height="724" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/8.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="1000" data-height="579" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/3.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="1000" data-height="650" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/4.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="1000" data-height="650" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/4.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="700" data-height="932" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/6.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="1000" data-height="724" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/8.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="1000" data-height="600" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/9.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="600" data-height="799" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/7.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="600" data-height="804" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/1.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="600" data-height="791" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/2.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="1000" data-height="579" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/3.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="1000" data-height="650" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/4.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="1000" data-height="650" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/4.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="600" data-height="804" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/1.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="600" data-height="791" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/2.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="1000" data-height="579" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/3.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="1000" data-height="650"src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/4.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="700" data-height="932" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/6.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="1000" data-height="724" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/8.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="1000" data-height="600" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/9.jpg"></div>
  <div><img class="item" data-width="600" data-height="799" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/7.jpg"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#masonry { 
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
div#masonry img {  
    position: static !important;
    bottom: auto !important;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
} 

#masonry div{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#masonry:after {
    -ms-flex: 20 150px;
    -webkit-flex: 20 150px;
    flex: 20 150px;
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    height: 1px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px){
    #masonry:after {
        -ms-flex: 500 300px;
        -webkit-flex: 500 300px;
        flex: 500 300px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px){
    #masonry:after {
        -ms-flex: 100 250px;
        -webkit-flex: 100 250px;
        flex: 100 250px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    #masonry:after {
        -ms-flex: 50 200px;
        -webkit-flex: 50 200px;
        flex: 50 200px;
    }
}
```

JS(using jquery):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      var o = {};
      $("#masonry img").each(function(){
           o.base = parseInt($(this).data("width"),10)/parseInt($(this).data("height"),10);

           o.grow = Math.round(o.base*1e3)/100;
           o.h    = Math.round(190*o.base);

           $(this).parent().css("flex",o.grow+" "+o.h+"px");
           $(this).parent().css("min-height",Math.round(o.h/o.base));
      });
 });
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KeLvh)

Images have the same height in a row whatever orientation and dimensions.

A little bit of javascript to know the images's ratio for height desired and that's it.

Comment: Most epic, simplistic code for fixing gallery grid I've seen... EVER!!!!! Thank you so much for sharing this! I've been banging my head with this for over 3 days now! I'll give you 50 points for this! :)

Comment: Glad you appreciate it ;)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/z85mwm92/) fiddle is close to what you want. It sizes all the images according to the set width and moves the images when the window is resized. It isn't perfect but it's a good start.

**trWidthAllow** is where you can start to build the rest of the function. It determines how many images can be fit (*side-by-side*) in the *window* (this can be changed to a parent div). It **floors** the value (*round down*) so that you don't get overflow (unless window is resized below **(padding*2)+maxWidth** *in other words, the image width plus the padding-left and padding-right values*)

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="thing">
                <img src="http://www.independent.co.uk/incoming/article8465213.ece/alternates/w620/v2-cute-cat-picture.jpg">
                <img src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/687/cache/bonobo-congo-ziegler_68751_990x742.jpg">
                <img src="http://static6.businessinsider.com/image/51c3212a6bb3f79c2000000f/this-space-picture-changes-our-understanding-of-how-black-holes-form.jpg">
                <img src="http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/411/cache/northern-lights-picture-aurora-borealis-september-2011-yukon_41173_600x450.jpg">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
table, tr, td {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    border:none;
}
#myDiv {
}
img {
    padding:5px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var maxWidth = 390;

var windowWidth = $(window).width();
var imgPadding = parseInt($(".thing img").css("padding"), 10);
var trWidthAllow = Math.floor(windowWidth / (maxWidth + (imgPadding * 2)));
//alert(trWidthAllow);
//alert(windowWidth);
//alert(imgPadding);
var ratio;
var numImgItems = $(".thing img").length;
//alert(numImgItems);
for (var i = 0; i < numImgItems; i++) {
    var actualWidth = $(".thing img:eq(" + i + ")").width();
    var actualHeight = $(".thing img:eq(" + i + ")").height();
    ratio = actualWidth / maxWidth;
    $(".thing img:eq(" + i + ")").css({
        width: maxWidth + "px",
        height: actualHeight / ratio + "px"
    });
    //alert(actualWidth + "; " + actualHeight);
}
/*$(".thing").addClass("myClass");*/
});
```

Comment: thx a lot for your reply and thx for code, but this is not i'm looking for. . 

in fact all image need to be on the same height ( more or less one pixel ), with ratio like google image or exemple above.

Comment: here is a [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hadtv)
i'm close to goal but now how fill complete width ( only the first )

i know flex: <'flex-grow'> <'flex-shrink'> <'flex-basis'>  is the property that i should use but how calculate flex-grows flex-basis like first ewample above ?

Comment: Ok I understand now. Does this link help? http://codegeekz.com/jquery-grids/, and from that page, I believe this: http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/ is what you're looking for. Scroll down to the "Images Layout" item and check out the preview. Easiest to use a plugin

Comment: hey it's a good start. now i need to find how do not crop my image. i'll back to you soon with my approach. many thx !!

Comment: To not crop the image, use the js code I posted above. Simply wrap all the images in a div with a class name and change the above code to your class name. Replace ".thing" in the code with your class name